# X11 freezes with VLC and kwin

Tags: freeze, vlc-media-player, xorg, kwin

When vlc hangs because of bad reception (network stream http or udp coming from a satellite receiver), sometimes the whole X11 freezes. Then only the cursor works, but everything else hangs.

When i disable compositing in with alt-shift-F12, it gets disabled after quite a while and the system works again (the stream itself now permanently hangs until stop and play again).
When not reacting with disabling and compositing, sometimes even the mouse doesn't respond anymore and switching to a console (which can take 1-2 minutes again) and killing vlc and kwin recovers the situation.
I am not sure if compositing is the problem or switching compositing only changes something, which affects the graphics problem.

Now I would like to report a bug (and possibly find a workaround). But I am unsure, if I should report to kwin, vlc or xorg. What's most likely to cause the hang?